# Load custom modules from root directory with NPM

Tags: node.js, npm

Probably a really simple answer but I'm lost.  If I'm in a file several directories below root is there a way I can `require ('mylib/module1')` in that file and have it search for the 'mylib/module1.js' from the root rather than the relative path of where I'm using the `require` statement?

Obviously if I `require('underscore') it will just look for it in`package.json`, but I couldn't find any way to set up a reference in`package.json` to point the right folder, something like:

dependencies: {
    "mylib/module1" : "./mylib/module1.js"
}

I did find a reference to `browser` that allows you to map to client-side files, but I'm looking for something that will work on the back-end.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.devworkflows.com/posts/using-local-npm-modules-in-npm-v2-0/

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it without needing npm support is to rename your `mylib` folder to `node_modules`. You can then simply `require('module')`.

The reason this works is because `require` searches recursively up the directory structure until `/` looking for folders called `node_modules`. This very simple mechanism allows node to have multiple levels of **lib** directories which can be overridden at multiple "local" level where necessary. For example, you can have the following directory structure:

```
/usr
    /home
        /diplosaurus
            /node_modules
                module1.js   <-------- version 1
            /code
                /node_modules
                    module1.js  <-------- version 2
                /projectA
                    /node_modules
                        module1.js  <------- beta version
                    main.js
                /projetB
                    main.js
```

All code in your home directory would use version 1 of `module1` but code in the `code` directory would use version 2 and `projectA` uses the beta version.

This also means that you can let npm manage your project's `node_modules` directory yet maintain a manually managed, higher level `node_modules` directory for your personal libraries.